# diagrama de sankey d3.js problema com grandes dados

Tags: d3.js

alguem me sabe dizer porque nao consigo ler este json e mostrar no sankey

tenho de usar d3.js
se meter menos dados funciona
   lista do json 
http://pastebin.com/p3mzVb2m

Answer (score 1):

O plugin Sankey do D3 utiliza a *posição* numérica (índice) do elemento no array `nodes` para as propriedades  `source` e `target` do array `links`. No seu exemplo você está usando nomes. Você pode pré-processar o arquivo antes do uso para fazer a substituição, ou fazer a substituição em tempo real usando:

```
d3.json("sankey-data.json", function(error, data) {
   if(error) console.log(error)

   function getIndex(name) { // descobre o índice do nome
       return data.nodes.findIndex(function(d) {
           return d.name == name;
       });
   }

   for(var i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++) { // troca nomes por índices
       data.links[i].target = getIndex(data.links[i].target);
       data.links[i].source = getIndex(data.links[i].source);
   }

   // agora o array *data* pode ser usado pelo sankey
```

...

Um segundo problema que você pode encontrar é um loop infinito, pois me parece que seus dados contém caminhos circulares, o que não é suportado pelo Sankey. Teste seu arquivo com menos dados (removendo os caminhos circulares) e depois dê uma olhada em https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/pull/39 que cita algumas alternativas para lidar com essa questão.

Comment: ola ja consegui . o que fiz foi colocar nos dados origem um nome antes tipo origem+ valor do campo e assim ja gera o grafico com nomes iguais ele passa-se um bocado

Comment: converti os dados para csv. ja nao estou a usar o json. parece-me mais lento a meu ver.

Comment: ja vi porque nao dava, bascimante tenho de gerar dois tipos de nodes para  as duas colunas por exemplo , nome : "a " e nome: "a" e depois fazer o mesmo na query origem destino ....dar um espaçamento e ja funciona...

Comment: é possivel fazer uma filragem nova dos dados ou seja sem fazer uma query nova a bd mostra apenas os que vao de source!=target